# fragment visible while going back from an activity to other activity

Tags: java, android

I have 2 activities A and B. A hosts 2 fragments A and B. What I do is from this fragment A, I start Activity B and on finish I go to Activity A and 
open Fragment B. In going to Activity A, I see fragment A for a second which should not happen. Here is my code -

From Fragment A -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), B.class);
intent.putExtra("hi, "bye);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, "performaAction");
```

In Activity B -

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("data", data);
setResult(resultId, i);
finish();
```

Now I am go to Activity A and in Activity A, I open Fragment B. During this process, I see Fragment A for a while which I dont want

In Activity A -

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (resultCode) {
            case resultId:
                new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        openFragmentB(); //Fragment transition
                    }
                });
                break;
           default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What purpose does async posting serve here? Have you tried called for fragment opening synchronously?

Comment: Yes but it it leads to a crash. So a fragment transition in onactivityresult was needed to be handled in a handler

Comment: Switching fragments never "leads to a crash" by itself. I suggest you check and fix that, then switch fragments in sync.

Comment: Seems to work without a handler.. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `Handler` part:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {

    switch (resultCode) {
        case resultId:
            openFragmentB(); //Fragment transition
            break;
       default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Explanation:

What you see is caused by you calling to switch fragments "sometime in the future", by using:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    openFragmentB();
  }
});
```

What that means is your system will open the fragment once it's done with its current queue of actions it already has to do on the same thread.

There should be no reason for switching fragments like that, the current thread already gives you control over what happens right then and there, by calling into your code in `onActivityResult`.